# Make a widget in Android

Tags: android, image, android-appwidget

I really wish to make a widget for my Religious app which can show an image everyday at 12 a.m. If user wishes to add a widget on the home screen then it should display an image which changes at 12 a.m. daily. I prefer to make something like a Picture Frame Widget but the user should not be requested to select the images and the interval should be every 24 hours starting from 12 a.m.

So far, I was able to do this:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int i=0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.inspirations);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
}
```

It shows the image but then I want to make sure that the new image should appear at 12 a.m. tonight.
I have never dealt with the widgets before, I would really appreciate if I can have anybody who can walk me through the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Make your `onUpdate()` method use the current date to decide which image to show, then arrange to call `onUpdate()` when the date changes.

To observe date changes, make a BroadcastReceiver listen for Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED which indicates that the date-time clock reached a new date. (While you're at it, listen for Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED as well, indicating that the clock was adjusted.)

Since AppWidgetProvider is already a BroadcastReceiver, you can use yours to receive these clock events by adding intent-filter actions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyAppWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
    </receiver>
```

In your AppWidgetProvider's `void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method, when any of these date/time intents comes in, call the `onUpdate()` method to refresh the widget contents.

**Note:** Due to [Android OS bug 2880](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2880), if the clock gets set backwards, the widget's date display might not update until the clock catches up to what was going to be the next day. In practice, this happens so rarely that you needn't worry about it *but* don't expect it to work if you set the clock backwards to test your code.